# Pandas: condition to string

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe and I want to delete string from dataframe, if some column contain `avito` and doesn't contain `telefony`.
I can write condition

`df1 = df[~df.url.str.contains(r"avito")]`

but I don't know how can I add condition with `telefony`
data:

```
url
avito.ru/mytischi/telefony/sim_karty_s_nulevym_balansom_bonus_689217820
avito.ru/moskva/blackberry_z10_714072090
avito.ru/moskva/telefony/blackberry_bold_new_rost-test_original_697592392
avito.ru/moskva/telefony/blackberry_bold_blask_new_e._a._c._rost-test_696289049
avito.ru/moskva/blackberry_z30_lte_4g_714023258
vk.com
```

Desire output:

```
url
avito.ru/mytischi/telefony/sim_karty_s_nulevym_balansom_bonus_689217820
avito.ru/moskva/telefony/blackberry_bold_new_rost-test_original_697592392
avito.ru/moskva/telefony/blackberry_bold_blask_new_e._a._c._rost-test_696289049
vk.com
```

Comment: Do you think `df1 = df[~df.url.str.contains(r"avito|telefony")]` ?

Comment: @jezrael does it mean, that string don't contain `telefony`?

Comment: @jezrael I think the OP wants `df1 = df[df.url.str.contains(r"avito") & ~df.url.str.contains(r"avito")]` but it's unclear without sample data, code their attempts and desired output. Could you actually add this

Comment: I add it to answer.

Comment: @EdChum - you are right. It was unclear for me too.

Comment: IIUC you want `df[~(df['url'].str.contains('avito') & ~df['url'].str.contains('telefony'))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to compound your boolean conditions and negate it:

```
In [18]:
df[~(df['url'].str.contains('avito') & ~df['url'].str.contains('telefony'))]

Out[18]:
                                                 url
0  avito.ru/mytischi/telefony/sim_karty_s_nulevym...
2  avito.ru/moskva/telefony/blackberry_bold_new_r...
3  avito.ru/moskva/telefony/blackberry_bold_blask...
5                                             vk.com
```

So the inner condition:

```
df['url'].str.contains('avito') & ~df['url'].str.contains('telefony')
```

here we are looking for urls that contain 'avito' and don't contain 'telefony':

```
In [19]:
df['url'].str.contains('avito') & ~df['url'].str.contains('telefony')

Out[19]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: url, dtype: bool
```

we then invert the above by enclosing in parentheses and using `~` like in the first code snippet

Comment: Thank you! I mean `df1 = df[~(df['url'].str.contains('avito') & ~df['url'].str.contains('telefony'))]`. And sorry for unclear question.